# How to load file in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm new at Typescript and have a syntax problem.  I want to load a user selected file (not using JQuery) and print the results to the console for now.  I was following some guides in JS but with no success.  This is what I have so far.

index.html

```
<input type="file" id="file-input" >
```

index.ts

```
document.getElementById("file-input").addEventListener("change", e => {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  var self = this;
  reader.onload = file => {
      var contents: any = file.target;
      self.text = contents.result; 
  };
  console.log(self.text.toString());
}, false);
```

This gives the following error in the console report:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous>
```

I'm not quite sure how to get the text from the buffer or if I'm even setting it up correctly.

UPDATE:
Current code with modifications:

```
document.getElementById("file-input").addEventListener("change", async (e) => {
  var file = (<HTMLInputElement>e.target).files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = file => {
      var contents: any = file.target;
      this.text = contents.result; 
      console.log(this.text.toString());
  };
}, false);
```

Comment: You need to wait for it to load.

Comment: Move the console.log **inside** the callback, which is called **asynchronously**, when the file is finally loaded, long after the file input change event listener function has returned.

Comment: Also, this `self` variable is unnecessary. Just use `this`: that's what arrow functions allow.

Comment: I thought that was the case @JBNizet, I moved the console.log inside the callback.  However, I don't get any console display (or errors) then.  I corrected the self variable usage.

Comment: That's because you never read the file. All you're doing it telling what to do when it's read. But you need to trigger the read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload

Comment: That makes sense.  Please forgive my dense-ness.  I have updated the modified example.  I had to cast e.target to get through compilation.  Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focus in on the code

```
  reader.onload = file => {
      var contents: any = file.target;
      self.text = contents.result; 
  };
  console.log(self.text.toString());
```

The order of execution you think it has:

```
  reader.onload = file => {
      var contents: any = file.target;
      self.text = contents.result; // FIRST 
  };
  console.log(self.text.toString()); // SECOND
```

The order of execution in reality:

```
  reader.onload = file => {
      var contents: any = file.target;
      self.text = contents.result; // SECOND
  };
  console.log(self.text.toString()); // FIRST
```

Hence you are getting the error as `.text` isn't assigned by the time `self.text.toString` runs.

## FIX

One way:

```
  reader.onload = file => {
      var contents: any = file.target;
      self.text = contents.result; // FIRST
      console.log(self.text.toString()); // SECOND 
  };
```